# Postgresql CREATE TABLE AS INSERT RETURNING

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, create-table, sql-returning

I trying to perform something like

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tblname AS (
  INSERT INTO tbl2 FROM SELECT(1,1) RETURNING a,b 
);
```

but i've got ERROR: syntax error at or near "INSERT";

Is it possible to combine **CREATE TABLE AS SELECT** and **INSERT FROM SELECT RETURNING** clauses?

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to put the `select` statement for a `create table as ` in parentheses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
create temp table tblname as
    with i as (
        insert into tbl2 (a, b)
        select 1, 1
        returning a,b 
    )
    select a, b
    from i
```